# Using Bootstrap and my own CSS together

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I know basic CSS, but I'm not experienced. 
I want to use bootstrap's CSS file, but I want to add my own style codes too. What should I do for that?
Should I add Bootstrap styles first and then mine? Is that the best way?

Comment: Bootstrap first, yours after.

Comment: If you're new to css, it's probably a bad idea to just throw a framework in first. Learn CSS, then learn how to manipulate a framework.

Comment: As others said, Bootstrap first. You could also consider customizing Bootstrap, such as colors for buttons/text. This can be done prior to downloading on bootstrap's customize page, or using a tool like http://bootswatchr.com/create which provides visual changes (full disclosure - I've never used the site - it was the first google result, a better tool may exist...)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You will have the stylesheets order like this, first you will include bootstrap css, then your stylesheet file. Why is that? Because that way you can overwrite the classes from the framework without using !important. You can write your own classes and include them in your layout, you can use bootstrap classes and make adjustments to them as you need. When you mix your classes and bootstrap classes check what attributes are added from their classes, do you need them or not etc...

Example

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
  /* Your external css file will go here. This is just for testing :) */
  
.mycustombtn{
  background: #000;
}

</style>  


<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger mycustombtn">Danger</button>
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use Bootstrap with your css, just do that (in your head tag):

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<!-- Your file css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="your-file-css.css" />
```

You can even overwrite some directive, just put them in you file (but isn't a best practice).

Remember, always put the link to bootstrap before the link to your css file.

Sorry for my english

Answer (score 5):

It is all about CSS specificity.

If two properties have the same weight, the latter property is used.

You can override single CSS properties by declaring the property `!important`.

Example;

```
body {
  background-color: #000 !important;
}
```

It is an easy way to overcome CSS selector weight (or specificity) if you notice that Bootstrap styles overrides yours (helpful for a novice just trying out stuff).

But you should read more about specificity instead - http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/.

Comment: I've put a "up", because this answer helped me! The latest bootstrap (4.3.1) I don't know about the others, but "`!important`" was the solution!

Answer (score 2):

It would look something like this:

```
<head>
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="yourstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

You can put as many CSS links as you need.  I find it's usually best to put framework CSS files above your own.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the bootstrap css first and then user your own, but it will be tricky because of the bootstrap's css. Make sure you check always what bootstrap classes does.

Comment: Main problem is to use the same class & id names with Bootstrap, right? I'm planning to use unique class & id names for my css. Is that enough to prevent probable errors?

Comment: There are classes that may add things that you don't want, be aware of that. And try not to use !important so much. It is not the best practice.