# Using Bootstrap CSS combined with Custom CSS - is this practice bad?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

If I place a button with standard Bootstrap CSS and than apply a custom css on top of it, is that bad practice?

Should I scrap the Bootstrap altogether and use custom only? If so what is the cost in saving? I had another **web developer** advise me that these additional classes created overhead in compiling the web page. How can I measure the speed of what I personally think is insignificant?

Here is an example of where a link looks like a button, using bootstrap css classes:

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>
      .custom-btn-css{
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bold;
        border-radius: 30px;
        border-width: 0;
        margin-top: 15px;
        padding: 10px 32px;
        color: white;
    }
</style>

<div class="container">
  <a  class="btn btn-primary btn-large custom-btn-css" href="#">Button Example</a>
</div>
```

Comment: No, it's a normal practice.

Comment: Consistency is the key word ... if you think using your own styles along with the bootstrap there is no problem if you are consistent

Comment: There is nothing wrong with what you are doing, a lot of people over-ride the default bootstrap styles. If those button styles are going to be global I would personally re-use the class `.custom-btn-css` on other HTML elements as you have already written styles for it that can tehnically be recycled. Here is a handy article with helpful information regarding this matter: [How to customise bootstrap](https://bootstrapbay.com/blog/customize-bootstrap/)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. So there the design process I have chosen has insignificant overhead in the overall process correct? I mean I know my snippet is just a minor example, but it was one brought to my attention by another person while reading my code.

Comment: If you, or the other developer, is worried about number of classes causing a large overhead, Bootstrap is not for you! However, I've never really heard of that being an issue that causes any significance performance issues. As other commentors have mentioned, just be consistent with your custom classes by reusing what you can and you'll be fine.

Comment: @mcv Welcome dude!

Comment: You need to put those css inside your html file which means apply them after bootstrap css

Comment: @mcv You need to put those css inside your html file or use custom.css file and link it properly. I have updated an answer below in easy steps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132918/discussion-between-mcv-and-shivkumar-kondi).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem with that , first you need to look at this linik

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26640525/6572922

then you need to reffer How to Easily Add Custom CSS to Bootstrap with Examples

http://www.kodingmadesimple.com/2015/01/add-custom-css-to-bootstrap-examples.html

This link can clear your doubts

Comment: @Nailia I understand how bootstrap is applied, your initial link is much like my example above. My question is more over for peace of mind, that the process of custom css over bootstrap css is acceptable. I had another developer state that I shouldn't do that. So I posted the question here for the masses. I was just making sure that I was still following what I considered to be standard practice. However the examples provided affirm that what I was doing is correct, so I accepted it as the answer for this query. :)

Answer (score 1):

Put your css in **custom.css** file and you should follow this sequence to override bootstrap css.

```
</head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>


<body>
     <div class="container">
         <a  class="btn btn-primary btn-large custom-btn-css" href="#">Button Example</a>
     </div>
</body>
```

Or use Inline css as:(not recommended)

http://codepen.io/shivk/pen/QdyoRa

Comment: I understand that. I was speaking about the code example in this thread. Please remove this as a solution for it does not apply. :)