# Bootstrap is Changing Pre-Made CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So, let me get this straight, this title is extremely similar to previous questions, however, I tried what they told me and it wouldn't work. So, I have seen a couple of answers (i.e [Using Bootstrap and my own CSS together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26640250/using-bootstrap-and-my-own-css-together)) where they tell you to link to Bootstrap CSS *first* and then your CSS *last* so that you can have your CSS overwrite all of the previously existing stuff and such.

Anyway, I tried that and it didn't work. I am basically saying this because what normally looks like this:

[image: Before]

Has changed to this:

[image: After]

All thanks to Bootstrap! I am wondering if there is any other way around this since my CSS is already lined up after the Bootstrap CDN.

Code:

```css
::-moz-selection {
  color: #000000;
    background: #1ED6D3;
}

::selection {
    color: #000000;
    background: #1ED6D3;
}
#menuBar {
  height: 85px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  position: relative;
}
.titleButton, #contactButton {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-bottom: 3px groove;
  border-radius: 2px;
  line-height: 2.5;
}
.titleSpacer {
  margin-right: 10%;
}
.titleButton, .titleSpacer, #contactButton {
  display: inline;
}
.titleButton:hover, #contactButton:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 2px groove black;
}
#title {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 200px;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #7F7F7F;
  font-weight: 500;
}
#searchResultsTitle {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #7F7F7F;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: none;
}
#subtext {
  color: #47BC47;
  font-weight: normal;
}
#subtitle {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #3D3D3D;
  font-size: 26px;
  margin-top: 75px;
}
#searchBox {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: 3px solid #B2B2B2;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 65px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}
#searchBox:focus {
  outline: none;
}
#downArrow {
  width: 50px;
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 9px;
}
.hoverText {
  cursor: pointer;
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
 
body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #1ED6D3;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
#searchButton {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
  margin-left: -65px;
}
#searchButton:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#searchBox, #searchButton {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Home | CyanCoding</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="home.js"></script>
    <link rel="icon" href="Logo.ico">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Montserrat|Open+Sans|PT+Sans|Questrial|Raleway|Roboto|Work+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2 id = "subtitle">Search through 25+ programs</h2>
    <input type = "text" autocomplete = "false" id = "searchBox" name = "searchBox" placeholder = "Search for a program">
    <img id = "searchButton" src = "https://coursesearch.uchicago.edu/cs/prdguest/cache/UC_SEARCH_ICON_170616.PNG">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please share your code by adding a snippet to your post

Comment: I don't think this is necessary. I have already mentioned that my Bootstrap is linked before my CSS and I see no reason why you would need my CSS or HTML code after having said that.

Comment: Use the dev tools / code inspector to step through the relevant elements and see what's overriding your styles, then adjust yours accordingly (or don't use Bootstrap's class names if you don't want it overriding your styling).

Comment: Also I'm guessing this is due to Bootstrap's input height settings that you're probably not directly overriding.

Comment: It would help to see your html and css. Bootstrap is applying a style to something you are not overriding in your css

Comment: Looks like a specificity issue.  A majority of Bootstraps form CSS apply to the element directly, rather than a class.  Your CSS just isn't doing enough to UNDO what Bootstrap is applying.  Use your inspector to find out where the problem is.

Comment: Add box-sizing:content-box to your #search-box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that bootstrap was overriding the `box-sizing` setting on your `input` from `content-box` to `border-box` so your `input` padding was included inside the element `50px height`.

Bootstrap had also set your search button image to `middle` and not the default `baseline`.

I've added a comment to your `css`, where I've made updates.   Basically, the changes look like this:

```
#subtitle {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #3D3D3D;
  font-size: 26px;
  margin-top: 75px;
  font-weight: bold; /* Added */
}

#searchBox {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: 3px solid #B2B2B2;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 65px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  box-sizing:content-box; /* Added */
}

#searchButton {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
  margin-left: -65px;
  vertical-align:baseline; /* Added */
}
```

See running code below:

```css
::-moz-selection {
  color: #000000;
    background: #1ED6D3;
}

::selection {
    color: #000000;
    background: #1ED6D3;
}
#menuBar {
  height: 85px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  position: relative;
}
.titleButton, #contactButton {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-bottom: 3px groove;
  border-radius: 2px;
  line-height: 2.5;
}
.titleSpacer {
  margin-right: 10%;
}
.titleButton, .titleSpacer, #contactButton {
  display: inline;
}
.titleButton:hover, #contactButton:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 2px groove black;
}
#title {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 200px;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #7F7F7F;
  font-weight: 500;
}
#searchResultsTitle {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #7F7F7F;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: none;
}
#subtext {
  color: #47BC47;
  font-weight: normal;
}
#subtitle {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #3D3D3D;
  font-size: 26px;
  margin-top: 75px;
  font-weight: bold; /* Added */
}
#searchBox {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: 3px solid #B2B2B2;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 65px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  box-sizing:content-box; /* Added */
}
#searchBox:focus {
  outline: none;
}
#downArrow {
  width: 50px;
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 9px;
}
.hoverText {
  cursor: pointer;
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
 
body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #1ED6D3;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
#searchButton {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
  margin-left: -65px;
  vertical-align:baseline; /* Added */
}
#searchButton:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#searchBox, #searchButton {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Home | CyanCoding</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="home.js"></script>
    <link rel="icon" href="Logo.ico">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Montserrat|Open+Sans|PT+Sans|Questrial|Raleway|Roboto|Work+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2 id = "subtitle">Search through 25+ programs</h2>
    <input type = "text" autocomplete = "false" id = "searchBox" name = "searchBox" placeholder = "Search for a program">
    <img id = "searchButton" src = "https://coursesearch.uchicago.edu/cs/prdguest/cache/UC_SEARCH_ICON_170616.PNG">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would help the OP if you pointed out the code that makes a difference and why it solves the issue. This would also be helpful to others in the community who bump into this question afterwards

Comment: @ochi Thanks Ochi, you are right my comment was too brief, I've fixed that now.

Comment: You are welcome! I am glad you are able to help the OP and I was able to improve your answer a bit for others ;)